# Problem with finding DNL and INL of a DAC from its datasheet

Tags: datasheet, dac

Regarding my [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/612343/a-question-about-interpreting-dnl) I'm interested is the error between consecutive step sizes of [this DAC](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac8554.pdf?ts=1648690929969). I need to know DNL and INL of this DAC.

I searched for keywords for INL and DNL in the datasheet but couldn't find any such specs. Does the datasheet include any specs which is at least gives an idea about DNL and INL?

Comment: I cannot find a value for Integral nonlinearity.

Answer (score 1):

From the data sheet you linked, from the Electrical charactestics section (page 2)

Relative accuracy  (what they call integral non-linearity or INL)
Measured by line passing through codes 485 and 64741
typical ±4 LSBs, worst case ±12 LSBs

They don't use codes 0 to 65k for defining the straight line as it's a rail-to-rail voltage output part, and they just don't work well within a few mV of either rail.

Differential non-linearity (DNL)
16-bit monotonic
typical ±0.25 LSBs, worst case ±1 LSBs

'Monotonic' tells you that the worst case is +/- 1 LSB, an increase in code will never get you a decrease in output voltage.

Answer (score 0):

On that particular datasheet, they give "full scale error" rather than INL.  That is given as a percentage of full scale range.  If you prefer LSB, use the "relative accuracy" section.  Look in the "static performance" section under electrical characteristics.

This is a MUCH more accurate DAC than the last one you were considering.

Answer (score 0):

DNL = ±1LSB and INL = ±4LSB

p23 from linked datasheet

> DIFFERENTIAL AND INTEGRAL NONLINEARITY

> The DAC8554 uses precision thin film resistors to achieve monotonicity and good linearity. Typical linearity error is ±4LSBs, with a ±0.3mV error for a 5V range. Differential linearity is typically ±0.25LSBs, with a ±19µV error for a consecutive code change.

p2

> Differential nonlinearity 16-bit monotonic ±0.25 Typical ±1 LSB Max

[image]